# What is the negation of this set?

Tags: logic

statement: $[\forall x \in X,  \exists r> 0 : N_r(x) \subseteq X] \iff [\delta(X) \cap X = \emptyset]$

negation: $[\exists x \in X, \forall r > 0 : (x \in N_r(x) \land x \notin X)] \iff [\delta(X) \cap X \neq \emptyset]$

because I thought that [$N_r(x) \subseteq X] \equiv \forall x([x \in N_r(x)] \Rightarrow [x \in X])$

I think that there is a problem, but I didn't catch it, shall you give me a hint or explain the answer?

Comment: Your question is not clear. What is your main question? I mean the source.

Comment: @Alearner: it asked that finding the negation of the statement and  I wrote the statement. It is the only question asked to find the negation of the statement

Comment: I found the negation, but I am not sure that it is true or not, so I need some help

Comment: What does mean by $\forall \in X$?

Comment: @Alearner: I edited now, my bad

Comment: Did you mean $\delta(X)$ by boundary of $X$?

Comment: @Alearner: Yeah, it means boundary of X

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have given a two sided true statement.

I take the first one as $A$ and the second one as $B$.

Then , the negation of this statement "$A \implies B$" is $A \implies not B$

Similarly, the negation of this statement "$B \implies A$" is $B \implies not A$

That means, $[\forall x \in X,  \exists r> 0 : N_r(x) \subseteq X] \implies [\delta(X) \cap X = \emptyset]$
The negation: $[\forall x \in X,  \exists r> 0 : N_r(x) \subseteq X] \implies [\delta(X) \cap X \neq \emptyset]$

Similarly, $[\delta(X) \cap X = \emptyset]\implies [\forall x \in X,  \exists r> 0 : N_r(x) \subseteq X]$

The negation: $[\delta(X) \cap X = \emptyset]\implies [\exists x \in X,  \forall r> 0 : N_r(x) \nsubseteq X] $

Finally, for the statement: $[\forall x \in X,  \exists r> 0 : N_r(x) \subseteq X] \iff [\delta(X) \cap X = \emptyset]$

The negation: $[\forall x \in X,  \exists r> 0 : N_r(x) \subseteq X] \implies [\delta(X) \cap X \neq \emptyset]$ **or** $[\delta(X) \cap X = \emptyset]\implies [\exists x \in X,  \forall r> 0 : N_r(x) \nsubseteq X] $

Comment: Should negation of $A \implies B$ be $A \land \lnot B$ ?

Comment: ,so Can I say that $\lnot (A \iff B)$ is $(A \land \lnot B) \lor (B \land \lnot A)$ ?

Comment: @Steve Josh hmm